# Making a face with lines and vertices inside, like a grid,

Tags: mesh, vertices, faces

I would like to be able to create a face, with lines and vertices inside that connect all the vertices to the ones on the other side. Pressing `F` will create a face inside the selected vertices like this:
[image: Mesh with a mirror modifier]

but, I would like all the lines to match together on the other side, like a grid. Is there a shortcut for doing this, or some other shortcuts that would do the same?

Comment: There is indeed a tool to do what you want. If you have an even number of faces you can use [**Grid Fill**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html#modeling-meshes-editing-grid-fill)

Comment: You could use the grid fill tool by pressing 'space' and then searching fro 'grid fill'. Or you can use the knife tool 'k' and add horizontal cuts between the vertices.

Comment: It says I need to select two edge loops. Is this an issue with the mirror modfier?

Comment: If you have a mirror modifier (please don't leave important information like  that unstated in your question...)  You have two choices: apply the modifier and use grid fill or create a new edge connecting the bottom and top vertices, and subdivide that newly created edge to have the same number of vertices as on the curvature. Then use grid fill. Again, grid fill will only work on an even number of vertices, an odd number will result in an error message,